# Difference between getDefinition and getDefinitionByName in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Can somebody explain what is the difference between getDefinitionByName and getDefinition inA AS3?

When I load an external SWF I can't use `getDefinitionByName` because I get an Error #1065.

But using `externalSWF_ContentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition` works OK.

So, why getDefinitionByName doesn't find the className?
I mean, if the definition is inside the applicationDomain of the loaded SWF, why is not in the main SWF too? (I'm using Flex).

Offtopic: I can't create new tags so I can't add the tags getDefinition and getDefinitionByName :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**getDefinition** is a method of an [ApplicationDomain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#getDefinition%28%29) which returns a definition of a class, namespace or function.

**getDefinitionByName** is a package-level function from [flash.utils](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29) which returns a Class object that you can use to instantiate new Objects.  The definition must already be loaded somewhere in your ApplicationDomain.

The reason you can't make getDefinitionByName with an external SWF is that it is loaded into a separate ApplicationDomain.  Your second example works because you are targeting the correct ApplicationDomain.  To make your first example work you must load the external SWF into your current ApplicationDomain like this:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("externalSWF.swf");
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(request,context);
```

This works because it passes the current ApplicationDomain as a property of the loader context.

Comment: OK, so getDefinitionByName() is some type of shortcut for ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition() in the main app?

Comment: In whatever ApplicationDomain you're in at the time, yes.

Comment: What determines what application domain you're in?  Is it the Application Domain (AD) of the class containing the method that makes the call to getDefinition (i.e. the one at the top of the calling stack)?